# Wordpress: How to change the order of taxonomy lists using facetwp

Tags: mysql, wordpress, facetwp

I want to change the order of my list when display using facetWP.
I have attached the image so that you could understand what i require.

[image]

Here is the query

```
$sql = "SELECT f.facet_value, f.facet_display_value, f.term_id, f.parent_id, f.depth, 0 AS counter FROM {$wpdb->prefix}facetwp_index f WHERE f.facet_name = '{$facet['name']}' AND post_id IN ($raw_post_ids) GROUP BY f.facet_value ORDER BY $orderby LIMIT $limit";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything to achieve that ?

Comment: I have tried by installing the plugin "Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order" but failed i think it can be solved by changing query which facetwp use to fetch the results.

Comment: please write those queries in question. please edit it.

Comment: please help anyone???

Answer (score 1):

Please see the last example on this page: https://facetwp.com/documentation/facetwp_facet_orderby/

Since this is a custom database table (not wp_posts), you will need to modify the SQL query itself, via the aforementioned filter.